# validates password length conflicting with form_helper user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to get around this? Basically in my user model i have a password validation to check and make sure the user has a minimum password length

```
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6 }
```

However, when I get the user to update additional info through a form helper, it refuses to update if I dont comment/delete the line above.
The following is some of my code in my user controller to update some user attributes in a db table

```
 def additional_info
  @user = User.find params[:id]
 end


 def update
  @user =  User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_addinfo)
     redirect_to @user
  else
     render action: 'additional_info'
  end
 end
 def user_addinfo
  params.permit(:years_business, :years_relationships, :years_careers, :years_lifeoutlook)
 end
end
```

Help is greatly appreciated. My website is structured around Michael Hartl's tutorial but i made some personal modifications.But for the most part, its exactly the same.

Comment: Did you add the password validation while having some users already in the database with password length less than 6?

Comment: No, i reset my database every-time i fix my code.

Comment: Use @user.update! method and you'll see the exact error as to why the record is not getting updated.

Comment: How are you storing the "password" attribute on User? Is it a database field, or is it an attr_accessor as many tutorials instruct you to do? (Or are you using `has_secure_password`?)

Comment: @KirtiThorat when i use that, it says password too short

Comment: @tdooner i have a password_digest column in my table, and I'm using has_secure_password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I understand.

You can look at [the `has_secure_password` source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5e9027bf2b3bdf3cafd2f1d5044caeea2065619/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L42) to see what validations, attributes, and other stuff it adds to your model.

As you probably know, `has_secure_password` adds an `attr_reader :password` along with a `#password=` setter that calculates the `password_digest` whenever you assign something to the password attribute. This prevents the `password` attribute from being persisted to the database. (Good!)

But that means that when you call `@user.update`, it will be on a `@user` which will have a `nil` password.

The trick is that you only want to validate the length of the password when the password is initially set. You should be able to fix this problem by changing your validation line to read:

`validates :password, length: {minimum: 6 }, on: :create`

If you want to allow users to change their passwords, you will have to do something else, like

`validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: Proc.new { |u| u.password.present? }`

Let me know if that works. I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem so let me know if this isn't the fix you were looking for.

Comment: Sir, if I were anywhere near you i would buy you a beer! By the way, now since i have this update method, my logout isn't working. Is there a quick fix? 
`def sign_out   
     current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
 cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 self.current_user = nil
  end`
the error: undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass